# Connection close but i dont know how to open entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I make a query to the database where is what I have in my conexion class

```
public class DBConext:DbContext 
{


    public DBConext():base("myconnectionstring")//connection is correctly perfect
    {

    }

    public DbSet<persona> personas{get; set;}
}
```

In my class persona i have this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace MvcApplication4.Models.accesslayer 
{
    public class persona 
    {

        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int idCliente { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public string apellido { get; set; }
        public string ocupacion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my form I have this

```
@model MvcApplication4.Models.accesslayer.persona

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using(Html.BeginForm()) 
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.nombre)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.apellido)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ocupacion)
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the controller

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult insertar(persona prsn) 
{
    var db = conexion.StringCon;

    db.personas.Add(prsn);
    db.Save();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

But when I click in submit an error comes and says: Exception Details:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source File: C:\dev\vsprojects\MvcApplication4\MvcApplication4\Controllers\HomeController.cs    Line: 35
```

Exactly where is `db.personas.add(persn)`? I don't understand. A friend told me that the database was closed but I thought entity framework had no open and close. And I tried as well and nothing work. 
Suggestions?

Comment: Are you putting in a full connection string or a named instance when using the constructor of the DbContext?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use your `Context`, do this:

```
public ActionResult insertar(persona)
{
    using (var context = new DBConext())
    {
        context.personas.Add(persona);
        context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

This will open the context and all affiliated lists, and then you can use anything within the context inside this `using` statement.